# How do you simplify the union of multiple databases with the same parameters?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 3 databases that I'm trying to union into a single view for reporting. I created the following query and it works great:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW combined_db.schema.offices AS (

SELECT
    'au' AS location,
    CONCAT(location,offices.id) AS office_id, // Prefix location to office id
    offices.name AS office, 
    regions.name AS region,
FROM db1_au.schema.offices
INNER JOIN db1_au.schema.regions
    ON regions.id = offices.region_id
WHERE offices.status = 'ACTIVE'

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'nz' AS location,
    CONCAT(location,offices.id) AS office_id, // Prefix location to office id
    offices.name AS office, 
    regions.name AS region,
FROM db2_nz.schema.offices
INNER JOIN db2_nz.schema.um_master_zones
    ON regions.id = offices.region_id
WHERE offices.status = 'ACTIVE'

UNION ALL 

SELECT
    'us' AS location,
    CONCAT(location,offices.id) AS office_id, // Prefix location to office id
    offices.name AS office, 
    regions.name AS region,
FROM db3_us.schema.offices
INNER JOIN db3_us.schema.regions
    ON regions.id = offices.region_id
WHERE offices.status = 'ACTIVE'

ORDER BY office ASC 
);
```

This works great, but it's not very pretty and difficult to update. I tried to simplify this by using

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW combined_db.schema.offices AS (

SELECT
    CONCAT(location,offices.id) AS office_id,
    offices.name AS office, 
    regions.name AS region

FROM (
    SELECT *, 'au' AS location FROM db1_au.schema.offices WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'nz' AS location FROM db2_nz.schema.offices WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'us' AS location FROM db3_us.schema.offices WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
) offices

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM db1_au.schema.regions
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM db2_nz.schema.regions
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM db3_us.schema.regions
) regions
    ON regions.id = offices.region_id

ORDER BY office ASC 
);
```

Now when I run it I get an error saying "inconsistent data type for result columns for set operator input branches, expected VARCHAR(16777216), got VARIANT for expression [{2}] branch {3}". Can anyone spot what I'm missing in the simplified query?

Comment: `SELECT *` is risky because if the columns (and the correct types) do not line up in the same order across all tables in the union, it could result in this error.  Instead, consider listing out all columns explicitly.

Comment: In my instance they will always have the same order, but I hear you. Are you saying the the first way I wrote this is the best way to handle it since I'm not using `SELECT *`?

Comment: Why are you doing SELECT * when you are subsequently only using one column from each table in your outer select?

Comment: so use `select col1,col2...`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to turn this into a view, but adding it as an option in case it will help you.

You could do something like this to reduce the size of your union queries that have the same fields and parameters but different databases:

```sql
declare
    sql varchar;
    final_sql varchar;
    -- countries is a cursor variable that should return 'au', 'nz', and 'us' for COUNTRY_NAME
    countries cursor for (select country as COUNTRY_NAME
                          , 'db_' || country as DB_NAME
                         from your_table);
    res resultset;
begin
    final_sql := '';
    -- $$ is a multi line string delimiter
    for country in countries do
        sql := $$
                select
                'COUNTRY_NAME' as location,
                concat(location,offices.id) as office_id
                offices.name as office, 
                regions.name AS region,
                from DB_NAME.schema.offices
                inner join DB_NAME.schema.regions
                    on regions.id = offices.region_id
                where offices.status = 'ACTIVE'
            $$;
        sql := replace(replace(sql, 'COUNTRY_NAME', country.COUNTRY_NAME), 'DB_NAME', country.DB_NAME);
        
        if(final_sql != '')then 
          final_sql := final_sql || ' union all ';
        end if;
        
        final_sql := final_sql || sql;
    end for;
    
    res := (execute immediate :final_sql);
    return table(res);
end;
```

According to the [Snowflake docs for RESULTSETS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets.html), you cannot use a `RESULTSET` directly as a table. You also cannot wrap this inside of `CREATE VIEW` DDL. Perhaps someone knows, though, and can edit the answer accordingly.